# Why is Rank() not working as it should?

Tags: sql-server-2008

This is my table data :-

```
Insert Into tblProduct (ProductId,ProductName,Description,Category) Values (1,'Cinthol','cosmetic soap','soap');
Insert Into tblProduct (ProductId,ProductName,Description,Category) Values (1,'Cinthol','cosmetic soap','soap');
Insert Into tblProduct (ProductId,ProductName,Description,Category) Values (1,'Cinthol','cosmetic soap','soap');
Insert Into tblProduct (ProductId,ProductName,Description,Category) Values (1,'Lux','cosmetic soap','soap');
Insert Into tblProduct (ProductId,ProductName,Description,Category) Values (1,'Crowning Glory','cosmetic soap','soap');
Insert Into tblProduct (ProductId,ProductName,Description,Category) Values (2,'Cinthol','nice soap','soap');
Insert Into tblProduct (ProductId,ProductName,Description,Category) Values (3,'Lux','nice soap','soap');
Insert Into tblProduct (ProductId,ProductName,Description,Category) Values (3,'Lux','nice soap','soap');
```

When i issue this query :-

```
Select  ProductId, 
        ProductName, 
        Description,
        Category, 
        RANK() Over ( partition by ProductId Order By ProductId) As Rank
From tblProduct;
```

All i can see is `1st` rank in each row. Where are all other other ranks? row with productid `2` should have rank `6` since i am not using `DENSE_RANK()`. Why is the query not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're partitioning by ProductId - which means each 'partition' will start RANKing from 1.  Try removing the `PARTITION BY ProductId`.